# IndexedDB / PouchDB Blobs on iPad, Safari 11.3.1

Tags: angular, ipad, safari, indexeddb, pouchdb

I have an angular 5.2.9 PWA app that stores data locally to IndexedDB via PouchDB for offline use. This app stores photos as a Blob within a document. I do not use attachments. This works on Chrome & Edge browsers and Andriod but the Blob does not store or load properly on an iPad. The iPad is running Safari 11.3.1. When the photos are taken they display in my gallery just fine. After saving and retrieving via PouchDB I get a zero size Blob. Am I missing some Safari/iPad specific config or setting?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../../service/configuration.service';

import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

import { Inspection } from '../../model/inspection';
import { PhotoDialogComponent } from './../photo-dialog/photo-dialog.component';
import { InspectionPhoto } from '../../model/inspection-photo';
import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photo-gallery',
  templateUrl: './photo-gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photo-gallery.component.css']
})
export class PhotoGalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  photoDialogRef: MatDialogRef<PhotoDialogComponent>;
  inspection: Inspection;

  photoList: BehaviorSubject<Array<InspectionPhoto>>;
  currentUrl: BehaviorSubject<SafeResourceUrl>;
  currentIndex: number;
  length: number;
  rotate: string;

  constructor(public config: ConfigurationService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PhotoDialogComponent>,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public domSanitiser: DomSanitizer) {

    this.photoList = new BehaviorSubject<Array<InspectionPhoto>>(new Array<InspectionPhoto>());
    this.currentUrl = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    this.length = 0;
    this.rotate = this.config.getRotateImages() ? "rotate90" : ""; 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let db = new PouchDB('inspection-photo');
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true})
    .then(result => {
      return Promise.all(result.rows.map(row => {
      let item = new InspectionPhoto();
      item = row.doc;
      item._id = row.id;
      item._rev = row.rev;
      return item;
      }));
    }).then(list => {
      this.length = list.length;
      this.currentIndex = 0; 
      this.photoList.next(list);
      if(list.length > 0) {
        this.getImageUrl(list[0]);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ngOnInit db error' + err);
      alert('ngOnInit db error' + err);
    });

  }

  public getImageUrl(inspectionPhoto: InspectionPhoto): void {
    if(inspectionPhoto == undefined 
      || inspectionPhoto.Photo == undefined){ 
      return; }

    // alert('blob size: ' + inspectionPhoto.Photo.size);

    let modified: Date = new Date();
    let f:File = new File([inspectionPhoto.Photo], 
      "image" + this.currentIndex + ".jpg", 
      {type: "image/jpeg", lastModified: modified.getUTCMilliseconds()}
    );

    // alert('file: ' 
    //   + ' name: ' + f.name
    //   + ' type: ' + f.type
    //   + ' size: ' + f.size
    // );

    let url: string;
    try {
      url = URL.createObjectURL(f, {oneTimeOnly: true}); //.substring(5);
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert('1:' + (<Error>e).message + (<Error>e).stack);
    }

    let sanitisedUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
    try{
      sanitisedUrl = this.domSanitiser.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert('2:' + (<Error>e).message);
    }

    try{
      this.currentUrl.next(sanitisedUrl);
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert('3:' + (<Error>e).message);
    }
}

  public onNext() {
    if (this.currentIndex >= this.length - 1) {
      this.currentIndex = 0;
    } else {
      this.currentIndex += 1;
    }
    this.photoList.subscribe(list => {
      // alert('image:' + this.currentIndex);
      this.getImageUrl(list[this.currentIndex]);
    });
  }

  public onPrevious() {
    if (this.currentIndex <= 0) {
      this.currentIndex = this.length - 1;
    } else {
      this.currentIndex -= 1;
    }
    this.photoList.subscribe(list => {
      // alert('image:' + this.currentIndex);
      this.getImageUrl(list[this.currentIndex]);
    });
  }

  OnNewPhoto(): void {
    this.photoDialogRef = this.dialog.open(PhotoDialogComponent, {
    });

    this.photoDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        let inspectionPhoto = new InspectionPhoto();
        inspectionPhoto.InspectionId = this.inspection._id;
        inspectionPhoto.WorkOrderId = this.inspection.WorkOrderId;
        inspectionPhoto.TaskId = this.inspection.TaskId;
        inspectionPhoto.EquipmentId = this.inspection.EquipmentId;
        let db = new PouchDB('inspection-photo');
        let files: File[] = Array.from(this.photoDialogRef.componentInstance.files);
        files.forEach(f => {

          // alert('file: ' 
          //   + ' name: ' + f.name
          //   + ' type: ' + f.type
          //   + ' size: ' + f.size
          // );

          inspectionPhoto._id = this.config.uniqueID();
          inspectionPhoto.Photo = new Blob([f], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
          // alert('Blob size: ' + inspectionPhoto.Photo.size);

          db.put(inspectionPhoto)
            .then(result => {
              inspectionPhoto._id = result.id;
              inspectionPhoto._rev = result.rev;

              // alert('**** saved photo blob size:' + inspectionPhoto.Photo.size);

              this.photoList.subscribe(list => {
                list.push(inspectionPhoto);
                this.length = list.length;
                this.currentIndex = this.length - 1; 
              });
              this.getImageUrl(inspectionPhoto);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('OnNewPhoto db error ' + err);
              alert('OnNewPhoto db error ' + err);
            });
        });
      }
      this.photoDialogRef = null;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: IndexedDB Recognition fails on Safari 11 when using Angular 5 #766 https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/766

Comment: ...If you are having a similar issue this is due to a problem with recognising indexeddb on sfari with angular so pouchdb falls back to websql which does not support blobs. Unfortunately you cannot force the pouchdb adapter either.

Comment: It seems like your comments should be an answer.

Comment: Also, why can't you force the adapter?